# Auto Zoom on Mobile Devices keeps screwing up my Form

Tags: android, html, css, forms, flexbox

First off, I tried every fix I could find on stackoverflow and other sites to no avail. I think the issue lies somewhere else in my case.

Form works great on desktop and the emulated screen sizes in the dev tools, however on a live site and with an user on a mobile device as soon as you touch the input field, the field moves from :focus to :active the keyboard pops up, scrolls up the entire page and for some reason displays and locks the entire `<header>` into the viewport.

I can see how scrollbars appear and its moveable but the entire `<header>` blocks the viewport nonetheless. It even adjusts some of the elements? It even puts the cookies notif a layer down (which is the most top layer by coding)

I did all the fixes for the meta tags, which should prevent this even from happening to no help. Then I tinkered with the z-index to favour the `<Form>`, nothing. Then I removed the fixed and sticky properties for mobile only, nothing.

Oddly enough, as it is locking the `<header>` in the viewport it also messes up the flexbox, leads me to believe an /user-agent-stylesheet/ gets forcefully injected after all my css and this messes up the Form. I had this effect previously on a simple mailing list signup form, however on that site was only 1 input field and I actually liked the effect as it seemed pretty native and I suggested perhaps this is an flexbox integration or something.

However this Form has 7 `<input>` and 1 `<textarea>` and I absolutely need it. Would really really appreciate some help :) I dont know what snippets of the code I should share? So I pop some of the meta tags for that page and some of the specific css. Issues are on an android device, chromium based browser & mozilla based browser, all with the latest updates. Couldnt test it on safari so far.

```
 <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no">
```

.

```
html{
    scroll-behavior: smooth;
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    background-color: whitesmoke;
    font-size: 1.6em;
    font-weight: 200;
    line-height: 1.6;
    height: auto;
    text-align: center;
        width: 100%;
        margin: 0 0;
        animation: ease-in-out;
    }

header{
  width: 100%;
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
  min-height: 1.2rem;
  border-bottom: 0.3em ridge rgb(196, 82, 186);
  z-index: 1;
  font-size: 1rem;

  background-color: whitesmoke;
}

form{
display: flex;
flex-direction: column;
width: 50%;
margin: 3.2rem auto 0 auto;
background: var(--color-rose);
padding: 2.5rem 0.625rem;
border-radius: 0.99em;
box-shadow: 0.3em 0.2em 0.25em 0.26em rgba(20, 20, 20, 0.185);
border: 4px solid #e3e3e3;
border-radius: 0.99em;
z-index: 5 !important;
  

}




    @media only (phone stuff){
      header{
      margin-right: 0;
      width: 100%;
      z-index: 1;
      }
      header, .contact-container{
      position: relative;
    }
```

Let me know if you need additional info or code. Font size is more than 18px. (I read that a small font-size also causes this behaviour)

Comment: Can you share a screenshot of expected and or actual behaviour?

Comment: @AbishekStephen Hey! I made a gif of me using the live site on an android.
https://imgur.com/a/P9wVkDn

Comment: That is very bad UX behaviour. Does it happen with all other elements as well?